# DLL load failure with sklearn import

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to work with sklearn and I am getting an error when trying to import it. I have tried uninstalling both sklearn and scipy and reinstalling them but neither appears to have worked.

Here is my import clause:

```
from sklearn import datasets
```

And here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a2f5133f2834> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn import datasets
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      5 plt.style.use('ggplot')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     24 from . import _joblib
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\class_weight.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
      8 
      9 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>
     24 from contextlib import suppress
     25 
---> 26 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan, parse_version
     27 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     28 from ..exceptions import PositiveSpectrumWarning

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>
    287     from ._scipy_sparse_lsqr_backport import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
    288 else:
--> 289     from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
    290 
    291 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py in <module>
    112 from .dsolve import *
    113 from .interface import *
--> 114 from .eigen import *
    115 from .matfuncs import *
    116 from ._onenormest import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py in <module>
      7 
      8 """
----> 9 from .arpack import *
     10 from .lobpcg import *
     11 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py in <module>
     18 
     19 """
---> 20 from .arpack import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py in <module>
     40 __all__ = ['eigs', 'eigsh', 'svds', 'ArpackError', 'ArpackNoConvergence']
     41 
---> 42 from . import _arpack
     43 arpack_int = _arpack.timing.nbx.dtype
     44 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why this is occurring and more importantly, how to address it?

Answer (score 0):

Possible that C++ runtime library is missing.

See here [this Github issue](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4780#issuecomment-644214783) for potential solutions:

> As a workaround, try to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads), or import matplotlib before skimage, or `python -m pip install msvc-runtime`.